# Python - apache cgi-bin script works/doesn't work with different python installations?

Tags: python, apache, cgi

I have a file `test.py` in my `cgi-bin` folder for apache. 
The file looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print("Content-type: text/html\n\n")
print("Hello world!")
```

Then, if I go to `www.<mywebsite>.com/cgi-bin/test.py`, the page successfully shows `Hello world!`

**But, if I change my header line in my python script to**

`#!/home/kalaracey/python2.7/bin/python`

when I navigate to `www.<mywebsite>.com/cgi-bin/test.py`, I get a Error 500 Internal Server error. Any ideas?

I have done `sudo chmod 755 test.py` and can call it with just `./test.py` with both versions of the header line.

**EDIT:** Per @Anony-Mousse 's comment, here's the Apache error_log that applies:

```
[Wed Jul 11 17:33:40 2012] [error] [client <ipaddress>] (13)Permission denied: exec of '/var/www/cgi-bin/test.py' failed
[Wed Jul 11 17:33:40 2012] [error] [client <ipaddress>] Premature end of script headers: test.py
```

Comment: **What does the apache error log say**?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I've added the two lines of the error_log that apply; it looks like it's a permissions error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the web server user have access rights to your custom python installation?

If it cannot execute `/home/kalaracey/python2.7/bin/python` it cannot execute your script.

Make you have `chmod -R go+rX /home/kalaracey/python2.7` and `chmod go+x /home/kalaracey/python2.7/bin/python`.

Comment: I executed both of those commands but still nothing. Any ideas? My permissions for `~/python2.7/` are `drwxr-xr-x`; `~/python2.7/bin` is `drwxr-xr-x`; and `~/python2.7/bin/python` is `-rwxr-xr-x`

Comment: Actually, I realized that the permissions for `home/kalaracey` (i.e., `~`) are just `drwx------`. Changing permissions for it via `chmod -R go+x /home/kalaracey` allowed the script to run. Thanks for all your help @Anony-Mousse!